# How do I interpret a variable that is significant in a multinomial logistic model but not in an ordinal logistic model?

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, ordered-logit, multinomial-logit

After fitting a multinomial and ordinal logistic models, an interesting results shows up.

This is the multinomial logistic regression:
[image]

And this is the ordinal logistic regression:
[image]

As you can see, the Female dummy variable is small and insignificant in the ordinal regression while in the multinomial regression the same variable is significant and big.

I understand that the ordinal regression has limited the cumulative probabilities to have their own slope. How does the female variance get lost in a model with less variables?

Does the constant for the cutoff1 provide any hints?

Comment: One possibility is that in ordinal regression the levels of the dependent variable are being assigned some undesirable order, e.g.,  Continue, Withdraw, Undecided.  This could easily fail to replicate a relationship observed when treating the levels without underlying order.